# zxing qr-code scanner converts upper to lower on android?

Tags: java, android, barcode, qr-code, zxing

I have a very strange problem. I am using **zxing** on **android** for qr-code scanning. It scans url, get the **json** response of the url and then execute data. The problem is when q-code scans the url it converts all the uppercase letters i the url to lower case, which should not happen.

Eg. If i encode:

> http://example.com/test.php?id=6tGHy

to qr-code.

and then when this qr-code is scanned, it returns:

> http://example.com/test.php?id=6tghy

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

No, it definitely doesn't lower-case URLs -- I wrote it and am well aware this breaks URLs!

Your encoder is probably lower-casing it. To find out, upload the QR code here and it will show you exactly what it encodes: http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx

Comment: "I wrote it"! Wow, what an answer!